# How to make ultra instinct aura?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

[image]

I am trying to make a aura like the one above but can’t get it right. I have tried using a transparent shader mix with a emission shader but it ends up way off from what I’m trying to achieve.

Here’s what it looks like without a character
 [image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Oh and if you click transparent under renders it takes they volume away from a material. not sure if this helps but maybe just try iy out